# Div dropping down for no reason?

Tags: html, css

I have the following css

```
.container {margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto; width:1020px;}
.body {float:left; width:1020px;}
.leftcont {float:left; width:206px;}
.left {float:left; width:205px;border-right-width:thin;border-right-style:solid; padding-right:5px;}
 .right {float:left;width:813px; padding: 20px;}
```

The html:

```
<div class="container">
<?php
include("navigation/footNav.php");
?>



<div class="body">
    <div class="leftcont">
        <?php
        if($session->logged_in){ 
            include("navigation/sideLogIn.php");
        }
        else
        {
            include("navigation/sideLogOut.php");
        }
        ?>
        <div class="left">
            <div class="bar">
                <h1 class="title">Page Menu</h1>
                <div class="arrow"></div>
                <a href="/settings.php" class="list">My Settings</a>
                <br />
                <div class="arrow"></div>
                <a href="/process.php" class="list">Logout</a>
                <br />
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
    <div class="right">
        THis text
    </div>
</div>
<?php
include("navigation/footer.php");
?>
```

leftcont and right are supposed to line up side by side. But for some reason, the right div is dropping below the left one?

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `.body` width is `1020px`, which will contain the `.leftcont`'s `206px` and the `.right` `813px`, but it *won't* hold it with that `padding: 20px` on there, which makes the width effectively `843`.

You either need to reduce the padding or width on `.right`, or expand the with on `.body`.

Comment: I thought padding was inside the div?

Comment: @Luke "The CSS padding properties define the space between the element border and the element content" src: http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_padding.asp

Answer (score 0):

```
206 + 813 + 20 + 20 = 1059
```

You need to decrease the width of `leftCont` or `right`, or decrease the padding of `right`.